Can I still play Overwatch 1?
I was wondering if I had a disc of Overwatch before Overwatch 2, if I would still be able to play it. I know the servers are down, but could I play the training room or a custom map?
I'm playing on Xbox.

it is differnt. I was asking spesifically about the training room

You are no longer able to download Overwatch 1 since the game has been taken off online stores.
Inserting a disc copy of Overwatch 1 into a console like the PS4 will cause the console to recognize the game as a copy of Overwatch 2 (here's an example via Reddit).
If you still had a copy of Overwatch 1 installed you'd be unable to get past the login screen as the game servers have been shut down and thus you are unable to access training mode.
